# How to enable Adobe Flash in Superbird browser for Windows

Tags: windows, browser, google-chrome-extensions, flash, chromium

I've been using the portable Windows version of the Superbird browser, a chromium derivative, and can't get it to recognize the installed Adobe Flash version. The same question has already been asked for the Ubuntu-version of the browser, but the solution is of course not compatible with the Windows one:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/626342/how-do-i-get-adobe-flash-functional-in-superbird-browser-in-xubuntu-15-04-64-bi

I checked Iron, another chromium-derivative, which uses Flash without problems. It references NPSWF32_21_0_0_197.dll in

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\

How can I get Superbird to use Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Superbird only works with the PPAPI version of Flash while Adobe will have the user download and install the NPAPI version through that browser. Installing it from here did the trick:

https://admdownload.adobe.com/bin/live/flashplayer21pp_ha_install.exe